# Difference between Integer.parseInt(“10“); and Integer.valueOf(“10“);

Tags: java

What's in Java the difference between

```
    Integer i = Integer.parseInt(“myString“);
```

and

```
    Integer i = Integer.valueOf(“myString“);
```

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valueOf` returns `Integer` object but `parseInt` returns `int` primitive data type